# How to find the maximum curvature of $y=e^x$?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, curvature

So I found the curvature to be $K = \dfrac{e^{x}}{(1+e^{2x})^{3/2}}$ but I don't know how to maximize this?

Comment: For large negative $x$, the denominator is basically $1$, so the whole thing is basically $e^x$ which is small. For large positive $x$, the denominator is basically $e^{3x}$, so the whole thing is basically $e^{-2x}$ which is again small. So by a Rolle's theorem-type argument, there is a global maximum which is also a local maximum. You can find the local maximum by taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero. (The calculation is a bit messy but doable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$K(x)=\frac{e^x}{(1+e^{2x})^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{\left(e^{-2x/3}+e^{4x/3}\right)^{3/2}}$$
hence to maximize $K(x)$ is the same as minimizing:
$$ f(x) = e^{-2x/3}+e^{4x/3}. $$
By solving $f'(x)=0$ we get that $x=-\frac{\log 2}{2}$ is the only stationary point of $f(x)$, hence the only stationary point of $K(x)$, and:
$$ K(x) \leq \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$

Answer (score 4):

We can differentiate and set equal to zero to get

$$\frac{e^x-2e^{3x}}{(1+e^{2x})^{5/2}}=0\implies e^x=2e^{3x}\implies\frac{1}{2}=e^{2x}.\tag{1}$$

Then solve to obtain $x=-\frac{1}{2}\log 2$.

**Note** - the various algebraic operations in (1) are possible since $e^x\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For future similar questions, it may be necessary to determine maxima/minima using the second derivative. So called "saddle" points may also need addressing.

Comment: Since there is a single stationary point, there is no need of computing the second derivative in order to understand if we have a minimum or a maximum. The original function is non-negative and its limit as $x\to +\infty$ equals zero, so we have found a maximum.

Comment: This may not be true for other functions.

Comment: I agree, but why to solve a particular question with a general technique that is more involved, if there is a shorter way?

Comment: No reason whatsoever for this particular question, but as I mentioned for future questions this technique may be useful/required. I like your answer also.